# Updating android app with Libgdx for 64-bit devices

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I have handful of apps in android on google play. I just need to update the app as per the below requirement mentioned by google recently. i.e., all the app has to be compatible with 64-bit .

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

**Questions:**

1. what code changes is needed in the app to make it compatible with 64-bit devices ?
2. Do we have 64-bit version of LibGdx available ?
3. If there is no 64-bit LibGdx available is there is any other work around to resolve this ?

Comment: you will find better answers in the libgdx irc or forums

Answer (score 21):

I've also received that email from Google and started to wonder if my game is compatible with 64-bit architectures.

Answering your question: as per official [libgdx changelog](https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3892) x64 support was added in version 1.9.0 (released 24.01.2016). So if your projected was set up using this version you're good to go! x64 is already supported.

If (like in my case) your project initially used version **prior 1.9.0** then code changes are required:

1. Add the following lines into root `build.gradle`:

```
    project(":android") {
       dependencies {
         ....
         // x32 support
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
         // NEW x64 support
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
         ...

       }
    }
```

Note, that you should add those two lines for each 3rd party library you're using, e.g. I have `gdx-freetype-platform`, so I added

```
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
```

2. Add the following lines into android-specific `build.gradle`:

   task copyAndroidNatives() {
   ....
   file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
   file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()

   ```
    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        ....
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        .....
    }
   ```

   }
3. Rebuild project and check that `arm64-v8a` and `x86_64` folders appeared in android->libs folder and that both of them contain `libgdx.so` file
4. Test it! Easiest way is to test on a real device since a lot of them support x64.

**Side note!**
If you're not sure if the libs are included go to Build-> Analyze APK in Intellij Idea\Android Studio and check that `lib` contains `arm64-v8a` or `x86_64` folders

[image: Analyze APK]