# Libgdx's 64-bit support: why am I still getting the "Action required" email from Google Play?

Tags: android, libgdx, 64-bit

Google Play has been sending emails entitled **"Action required: Update your apps to be 64-bit compliant by August 1, 2019"** to Android app developers.

I have been selling a small game (out of hobby -- I am not a professional game developer) on Google Play that uses the Libgdx library. I had followed the instructions as described in [Android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612128) to modify the gradle build scripts. The APK analyzer showed that I now have the relevant .so files (namely, libgdx.so and libgdx-freetype.so) in the **arm64-v8a** and **x86_64** folders. The new apk file was rolled out successfully a few days ago.

Nevertheless, I received another "Action required" email from Google today. Why? What can I do to comply with Google Play's requirements? How can I ensure that my app is built successfully with 64-bit support if I haven't any 64-bit device for testing?

Comment: I received the same email today and I already updated my app last week. I actually tried it on a 64bit phone and it's working, so I'll just wait August 1 and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of libGDX are you using? Are you using any other libs?

I use libGDX 1.9.8 in my game and I didn't receive an e-mail for that version. I did receive an e-mail for a libGDX 1.9.6 game though.

Comment: I use libgdx 1.9.6. Do you think the email is a false positive, or is there some genuine mistake?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try, but I don't want to roll out a new release that is found to be non-compliant afterwards. Have you upgrade your 1.9.6 game to 1.9.8 yet? Did Google stop complaining after the upgrade?